# Regular expression that doesn't accept single 0 but does accept 10

Tags: regex, swift

I have this regular expression:

`^[ 0-9A-Z] [ 0-9]{4}[0-9][/ ][ 0-9A-z]$`

and that works fine, but now I have to exclude the 0 in the construct `[ 0-9]{4}[0-9]` in this way.

The string `A     0/A` should get not match

The string `A    10/A` should get a match

So I have to check if the first occurrence of a number in the second group is a `0` or not.

How can I do that?
If anything or everything is not clear, just say so.

Comment: Maybe [`^[ 0-9A-Z] (?! *0)[ 0-9]{4}[0-9][/ ][ 0-9A-z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/6jBayo/1)?

Comment: Is it fair to say that your string length with the be the same every time?  That would be a very helpful, simplifying assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have to check if the first occurrence of a number in the second group is a 0 or not.

I think you need a negative lookahead:

```
^[ 0-9A-Z] (?! *0)[ 0-9]{4}[0-9][/ ][ 0-9A-Za-z]$
           ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jBayo/2).

Since the `[ 0-9]{4}[0-9]` matches 4 digits or spaces (there may be just 4 spaces) and the `[0-9]` matches a digit *obligatorily*, the `(?! *0)` will make sure that the pattern above does not match just spaces followed with a `0`.

Comment: nice will check if that fits my needs, thanks very mutch

Comment: Sorry, I missed when copied/paste: `[A-z]` must be replaced with `[A-Za-z]`, or you will also match `[`, `]`, `^`, `\``. Also, if it is for validation, you'd rather use `\z` at the end rather than `$` (in Swift, `let rx = "^[ 0-9A-Z] (?! *0)[ 0-9]{4}[0-9][/ ][ 0-9A-Za-z]\\z"`).